# How to make a mat-radio-group without the radio buttons?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to create a component that provides a list of selections to the user but allows only one selection to be made at any given time. The functionality of the mat-radio-group seems to fit that bill the best, but I don't want the actual radio button to be rendered next to the labels within my radio group. I want to expand the label and make any `(change)` event fire from a click event on the label itself.

What is the least "hacky" way to eliminate the radio buttons from my radio group, while keeping the labels as they were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also make a custom form control. The idea is that has a .html like

```
<select-component [(ngModel)]="valor">
    <div select value="1">One</div>
    <div select>Two</div>
</select-component>
```

We are going to make a directive that the selector was `[select]`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[select]',
})
export class SelectDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input('value')value:any;
  control:any;
  @HostBinding('class.selected') 
  get isSelected(){
    return this.control && this.control.value==this.value?true:undefined
    }
  @HostBinding('class.select')setClass(){return true}
  @HostListener('click') onclick() {
    console.log(this.value);
    if (this.control)
      this.control.setValue(this.value)
  }
  constructor(private el:ElementRef){}

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
      this.value=this.value ||this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML
  }
}
```

See that, in ngAfterViewInit we give value to `this.value` as the innerHTML of the div case you has not defined the value
There're two class binding, one .select -this alow us give .css to our component from app.main.component, one .selected, when the div was "selected".

The SelectComponent is a tipical custom form control, the "interesting" is that, in ngAfterViewInit, we ask about the "select" directive inside to allow comunicate the directive and the component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-component',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
   providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectComponent),
      multi: true
    }

  ]
})
export class SelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor,AfterViewInit  {
  @ContentChildren(SelectDirective)selects:QueryList<SelectDirective>;
  value:any;
  disabled:boolean=false;
  onChange:any;
  onTouched:any;

   writeValue(value: any[]|any): void {
    this.value=value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled=isDisabled
  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.selects.forEach(x=>{
      x.control=this
    })
  }
  setValue(value)
  {
    this.value=value
    this.onChange(value)
  }
}
```

And, voila!, the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyjnhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this, your stackblitz is exactly what I was looking for without having to torture another component to be something it isn't.